# UITableView Static Cells as a SubView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios5

Using Storyboard in iOS 5, I added a uitableview into an existing view controller with static cells, but when I run the app, the tableview does not show up. Everything else on the view loads fine.

How can I display the uitableview with static cells as a subview on a regular view controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New to iOS development, but from what I understand static cells only work within a UITableViewController.

Are you receiving the following error message:

> Static table views are only valid when embedded in UITableViewController instances

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons for a non-working tableview:

- you didn't set the datasource and the delegate
- you didn't fill the `numberOfRowsInSection` method
- you're not returning valid cells in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

What does your code look like?

Comment: Datasource and delegate are unassigned, I was under the impression since they are static cells they don't need a datasource. Wrong?  If they are static cells built in the storyboard, what is their to return in code?