# UITableView Content "Static cell" not working in iOS7

Tags: iphone, ios7, xcode5

I have a problem in my storyboard.It is working fine but when i try to change the content property of UITableView it caused following error

Assertion failure in -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2903.23/UITableView.m
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

I want to design a grouped tableview with static cell.Thanks in advance

Code

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
{ 
// Return the number of sections. 
return 2; 
} 
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{ 
return 3; 
} 
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{ 
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell"; 
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath]; 
return cell; 
}
```

Comment: if you don't share your code, we wont be able to help you

Comment: - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 3;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}

Comment: @AdnanChaudhry : add the code to the question,You can edit the question and add the code like this..see the edit option under the question

Comment: See the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9523604/3577656) for more information.

Answer (score 7):

if you use static cell, just comment all the UITableViewDatasourceDelegate method. so comment the following code:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
{ 
// Return the number of sections. 
return 2; 
} 
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{ 
return 3; 
} 
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{ 
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell"; 
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath]; 
return cell; 
}
```

Wish this will help you!

Comment: I am sorry that my answer is not correct! you should read [This related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9434849/2544997), this indicates that you can implement the UITableViewDatasourceDelegate but not like your way. Just like this:`- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section    
{
    return [super tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
`

Answer (score 7):

**Instead of using:**

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

//-> This is used when using prototype cells (e.g) Dynamic TableView

**Use:**

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [super tableView:tableView
                   cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

//-> Since you chose Static TableCells you don't need to reuse instead use the cells you created in nib

Comment: Great answer amigo!

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered same issue, and I think I found the way to work this out.

1. Create a Controller extends from UITableViewController to wrap its controller, it will have default UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource methods.
2. Remove UITableView delegate and datasource
3. Delete default UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource methods from your controller file, coz it's static cells, so if these exist, will not appear

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

When using storyboard the tableview cell must be registered in the storyboard.That means  cell must be added to the table and its identifier must be set.This identifier should be used in the code in `cellForRowAtIndexpath`

EDIT

In case of static cells the each purticular cells needed to be created in the nib and filled content via code or nib

Read this

- [Loading Table View Cells from a Storyboard](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW20)
- [Excellent starter](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50310/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-2)

Comment: I have registered tableview cell into storyboard and set identifier as well.

Comment: and the cell identifier is "Cell"?

Comment: when i run the project with tableview's property content with dynamic prototypes it is working fine.But when i change this property to Static cell then error shows.

Comment: thanks for your time and support.Yes cell identifier is "Cell".

Comment: Well static cells work little different,You need to create the cells in nib and load it

Comment: Thanks for your time.I am new to iOs can you please explain.

Comment: I shared a link in that there is a title "Loading Table View Cells from a Storyboard" Read that

Comment: I have following these two links but my problem is still the same!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737860/assertion-failure-in-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifierforindexpath

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to use static cells in a normal UITableView.

Instead you need to use UITableViewController to go with the static cells.

[this](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/111800-static-table-view-cells-only-work-in-a-uitableviewcontroller.html) and [this](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2012/05/07/static-table-views-with-storyboards.html) may or might help.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [YourArr count];
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 44;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell %d",indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell = nil;
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
     cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
}
else
{
    UIView *subview;
    while ((subview= [[[cell contentView]subviews]lastObject])!=nil)
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
}
```